# Cannot install libsyck0-dev

Tags: 11.10, package-management

I've been trying to follow [this](http://interfacelab.com/nginx-php-fpm-apc-awesome/) tutorial to install Nginx but my Ubuntu 11.10 cannot install libsyck0-dev. I am getting an error saying that package cannot be found. Any idea why it is happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial is written for Ubuntu 8.10. In Ubuntu 11.10 the package libsyck0-dev doesn't exist any more so you can't install it.

If you just want to install Nginx you can use the package from the official package sources. If that doesn't fit your needs for some reason try to find a tutorial that's written for a more recent version of Ubuntu.

Quite likely not only Ubuntu but some of the software it describes has changed in the 3 years since the tutorial has been written, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Did you find any documentation that says the package is not available? I'm only asking so that next time something similar happens, I won't have post another question.